# Objective-C cocoa touch: declaring properties over and over different view controllers

Tags: objective-c, properties, declaration

This might be a stupid question, but I've found myself getting tired of declaring same property over and over multiple view controllers. Is there a better design to do something simple as below:

Consider this:
I have a SoundManager class that is used throughout my iphone project. This class simply plays audio (click sound) when a user presses button.

Now, I have been doing this:

**ViewController A: .h**

```
SoundManager *mgr;
@property (nonatomic,retain) SoundManager *mgr;
```

**ViewController A: .m**

```
@synthesize *mgr;
```

and in viewDidLoad

```
if (mgr == nil)
  mgr = [[SoundManager alloc] init];
```

Then I repeat this over all my view controllers. This is cumbersome to say the least. There must be a better way of doing something like this - or at least a code generator utility that I could use?

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: subclass UIViewController and declare the variables there, allocate them in viewDidLoad, then for all the subsequent classes, inherit from that subclass

Comment: If it is the same in 'every' controller, you can think about override a common controller withnsome utilities method in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a singleton for that class:

```
@interface SoundManager : NSObject
{
    //your ivars
}

//your @properties

//singleton
 + (id)sharedManager;

@end

@implementation SoundManager

//synthesize

static SoundManager *instance = nil;
+ (id)sharedManager
{
    //you may want to add a @synchronized() here
    if (instance == nil)
    {
        instance = [[SoundManager alloc] init];
    }
    return instance;
}
@end
```

Then call [SoundManager sharedManager] wherever you need a SoundManager instance.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the whole app uses the same instance of SoundManager? Perhaps a Singleton pattern would be more usable. Or otherwise create a custom view controller with the mentioned functionality and make all other view controllers inherit from this custom view controller.